# SEXTED as a child . Want to repent

Tags: sin, zina, jahannam

Brothers, I am a boy who is 14 and I am a Muslim.  Ever since I turned 13, I've tried to repent. When I was 12, I was in puberty where my hormones were raging and I **SEXTED** online with a 14-15 yr old girl who I didn't know. I don't know if she was a boy or a girl as I had a doubt that he/she was acting to be a girl. I got sent nude. I blocked her and felt guilty. Am I like the person who does Zina . Am I never going to be pious? Will I be a person in hell?

Comment: Repent, never do it again, Allah will forgive you.

Comment: Never say never and believe that Allah accepts your repentence, but nevertheless fear his punishment to avoid falling in big sins!

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum,

It is good that you know you have committed a crime as per Islamic Law, and you feel guilty for it. If you ask forgiveness from Allah SWT, He will definitely forgive your sins which you have committed openly or privately. In Quran, Allah SWT mentioned many times that He SWT shall forgive whoever is asking for forgiveness.

"إن الله يحب التوابين و يحب المتطهرين" This verse of Quran means "Verily, Allah SWT loves those who repent and He SWT loves the people who purify themselves"

But the sin shouldn't be repeated. You can ask for forgiveness and consider that sin as a sin, you shall do Taubah and never repeat that again.

Please do Taubah! He shall forgive you.

Thank you